# soapUI - REST API, parameters as variables in request body are empty

Tags: soapui, rest-api, rest

soapUI 5.5.0, community edition.

Created REST requests with parameters (style = plain).
Wanted to use them in request body as variables, but that did not work.
Tried `"${#firstName}"` and `"{firstName}"`

The result was

```
"firstName": "",[\n]"
```

The call works fine with all values specified.

[image]

Comment: A google search revealed you're definitely not the only one wrestling this in SoapUI. It seems to be related to different scopes of your variables. I have no clear answer, but I can share some links like [this one](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Using-parameters-in-JSON-Body-in-REST-HTTP-POST-method/td-p/31245), [this one on property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html), or [another forum post](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-pull-property-value-to-the-next-json-body-request-using/td-p/134061).

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
${#VariableScope#VariableName}
```

Ex-

```
${#Project#firstName} --> For project level variable
${#TestSuite#firstName} --> For Test Suite level variable
${#TestCase#firstName} --> For Test Case level variable
```